# Как в MindDecider узнать количество ресурсов/критериев?

Tags: c#

Создал проект на MindDecider сравнения между различными аналитическими программами и программами "карт памяти". Параметров у программ очень много и взвешивание всех на несколько часов затягивается. Начал писать в проекте скрипт выбора только важных мне критериев для взвешивания.

```
using System;
using Stuffs;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MindDecider
{
 public class CodeDom
 {
  public void NVP( Document.ScriptArgument a )
  {
    Document doc = a.Doc;
    Form form1= new Form();
    ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

    int d = doc.RootResource.Count;
    doc.MessageModal( d.ToString() );
    for ( int i = doc.RootResource.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i-- )
        {
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, doc.RootResource.[i].Name); 
        }

    form1.Controls.Add(listBox1);
    form1.Show();
  }
 }
}
```

В таком виде МайндДесайдер выдаёт ошибку на строку:

> ```
> listBox1.Items.Insert(0, doc.RootResource.[i].Name);
> ```

[image: Ожидался идентификатор at line]

Если вместо `doc.RootResource.[i].Name` любой строковый аргумент поставить, чтобы убрать ошибку, например, "Blablabla", то возникают другие ошибки:

[image: Не удаётся привести группу методов]

Отсюда два вопроса:

1. Как узнать количество критериев на Root уровне (и общее тоже)?
2. Каким образом, перебирая их, получать имена каждого?

Comment: `RootResource.[i]` - точка же лишняя

Comment: Точно! Спасибо. Первая ошибка ушла.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = doc.RootResource.ToFlatList()
```

преобразует в тип `List<MindDecider.Resource>`, включая рейтинг пункта в `a[0];`

Соответственно:

```
doc.RootResource.ToFlatList().Count
```

дает общее количество критериев и ресурсов.